# How do I get the total size from the 'size' command?

Tags: linux

I want to find the size of all the sections/segments of `libc.a`.

When I run size on it, I get many lines of output, with different file names. Here's a snippet of a couple of lines I get:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
    244       4       0     248      f8 init-first.o (ex /usr/lib64/libc.a)
    720       0       0     720     2d0 libc-start.o (ex /usr/lib64/libc.a)
     67       0       0      67      43 sysdep.o (ex /usr/lib64/libc.a)
    942       0       0     942     3ae version.o (ex /usr/lib64/libc.a)
```

Wouldn't it be possible to just output the total size of the all segments of `libc.a` using the `size` command?

Comment: I've removed the "bash" tag, since your question has nothing to do with the shell (you can invoke "size" just as easily from any other shell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size -t /usr/lib/libc.a` should do it.

Its the last line after adding `-t` option. So to extract only the last line pipe it to `tail -n 1`

```
$ size -t /usr/lib/libc.a  | tail -n 1
1534448    3764   19567 1557779  17c513 (TOTALS)
```

Comment: If you *only* want the total, `size -t /usr/lib/libc.a | tail -n 1`

Comment: @KeithThompson `tail -n N` can be written as `tail -N`

Comment: Yes, and I usually do that myself, but strictly speaking it's an obsolete option.  See [the GNU Coreutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils#tail-invocation).